# Series about conjurers in Central/Eastern Europe

Tags: story-identification

About ten years ago I read a book trilogy that circled around magicians which conjured demons (or some other form of intelligent extra-planar being) in order to do their bidding.

I remember the series taking place in Central/Eastern Europe during or after the Renaissance but before the Industrial Age. I remember it taking place mostly in Prague (which was the seat of a magical university or some such where conjurers were trained).

Additionally, I recall the conjured creatures having vaguely biblical sounding names.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bartimaeus_Sequence?

Comment: @Valorum that's it! Feel free to add this as an answer for a quick accept

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the '[Bartimaeus Sequence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bartimaeus_Sequence)' of books by Jonathan Stroud: *The Amulet of Samarkand* (2003), *The Golem's Eye* (2004), *Ptolemy's Gate* (2005).

Most of the series is set in and around London, but a significant part of the second book takes place in Prague. It's set in a parallel world where the governing class are all magicians, who rule through their ability to summon demons (spirits) from "the Other Place" and subjugate them to their will. About a century before the books' setting, London and Prague were competing magical powers in Europe; Prague's power has waned after its defeat by Gladstone, but it still remains a significant magical centre.

There are djinn, golems, magical orbs and other such artifacts. The main character is a djinni with the biblical sounding name of Bartimaeus.

Comment: It's quite clear that you haven't read this series :-) (I recommend it btw.) In lieu of leaving huge comments, and since my own answer got nixed when you closed the question, I edited your answer with an axe to remove the inaccuracies (it's not set in "various European countries") and the irrelevant quote (book 1 has nothing about Prague, it can't be the one OP is remembering), and edited in some description which is relevant to the aspects that the OP remembers.

Comment: @Randal'Thor - Since OP has confirmed its a dupe, I didn't think it was worth putting in this level of effort. Good job you're here to do so. And the snarky comment is also much appreciated

Comment: Well, if it comes to that, wasn't worth posting an answer at all when the OP already confirmed it's a dupe in a comment. But if you're going to get rep for a correct identification, might as well be fully correct in the details too.

Comment: @Randal'Thor - It was already correct. You've hijacked my answer to add in a bunch of detail that *you* consider important.

Comment: No, not that "I consider" important: I edited to remove irrelevancies like magical orbs and the plot of the first book, and to **address what was mentioned in the OP** ("magicians which conjured demons (or some other form of intelligent extra-planar being) in order to do their bidding", "Central/Eastern Europe during or after the Renaissance but before the Industrial Age", "Prague was the seat of a magical university or some such", "vaguely biblical sounding names"), as a good story-ID answer should do.